# Vue baseUrl set in vue-router base

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

If I use a baseUrl in vue.config.js eg. '/directory1' i also must have base: '/directory1' when setting up vue-router otherwise it will route to '/'.

I want to be able to reference baseUrl in my vue app so I can have
base: baseUrl
in my vue router setup, is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vue.config.js` is just an exported object. There should be no problem in importing this object in your own code to read the baseUrl:

```
import { baseUrl } from './vue.config.js'

console.log(baseUrl);
```

Comment: It's located outside src directory, so in development it works but I didn't think it would work in production, but I guess it does. Thanks alot for this easy solution :)

Comment: @infinity1975 webpack takes care of adding all the imported files into the final bundle